# How to get select_date to retain selected values on re-render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a date_select:

```
<%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, {
                  :with_css_classes => true,
                  :order => [:month, :day, :year],
                  :prompt => true,
                  start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year - 100}, {:class => "select"} %>
```

When there are errors, and the page re-renders, the value are lost. With a regular select I set selected with the params, but I don't know how or it's possible with a date_select

Answer (score 0):

Ref [`this`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select), use `selected`

```
 <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, {
                   with_css_classes: true,
                   order: [:month, :day, :year],
                   selected: @date
                   prompt: true,
                   start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year - 100},
                   {:class => "select"} %>
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem I have though, is if the user only selects month, I want to be able to preselect month from the params <ActionController::Parameters {"date_of_birth(2i)"=>"8", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>""